# F# Microsoft Solver Foundation - NelderMeadSolver class

Tags: .net, optimization, f#, numerical-methods, ms-solver-foundation

Could anyone show me a sample code to use NelderMeadSolver class in F#?

For example, I want to minimize the following function: F(X, Y)

F = (X-1)^2 + (y-1)^2     where 0< X < 2 , 0< Y < 2   Answer is obviousely X = 1, Y = 1

I found an example for C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404040(v=VS.93).aspx

I would appreciate very much if someone can give me simple F# code to minimize the function above. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used Solver Foundation before, but here is a straightforward translation from [C# example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404040%28v=VS.93%29.aspx) (adapted to your optimization function):

```
open System
open Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common
open Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers

let xInitial = [| 0.; 0. |]
let xLower = [| 0.; 0. |]
let xUpper = [| 2.; 2. |]

let sqr x = x * x

let solution = 
   NelderMeadSolver.Solve(
      Func<float [], _>(fun xs -> sqr(xs.[0] - 1.) + sqr(xs.[1] - 1.)), 
      xInitial, xLower, xUpper)

printfn "%A" solution.Result
printfn "solution = %A" (solution.GetSolutionValue 0)
printfn "x = %A" (solution.GetValue 1)
printfn "y = %A" (solution.GetValue 2)
```

You should be able to add Solver Foundation's references and build the program. If you use the code in F# Interactive, remember to add Solver Foundation's dll files by referencing their exact paths.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to reference the SolverFoundation and retargeted the .net framework 4. But I am afraid that I can't compile the code above using VS 11. I think I have to instantiate the NelderMeadSolver class first. For example, let NMSolver = new NelderMeadSolver()  and then let solution = NMSolver.Solver ( .....) Here is the link for the class :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.solvers.neldermeadsolver(v=vs.93).aspx

Comment: What is the error? According to your link `NelderMeadSolver.Solve` is a static method, so you don't have to instantiate an object to use the solver.

Comment: It has an error on the line let solution =    NelderMeadSolver.Solve( ...)  saying that "the member or object constructor 'Solve' does not take 1 argument(s). An overload was found taking 2 arguments.  It seems that Solve method doesn't have one to one match with its C# couterpart. The link above gives some info regarding the arguments. But I don't know how to implement it. Thank you!!

Comment: It seems that the first argument should be the Func(T,Tresult) Delegate. Could you guide me what the syntax for the Func Delegate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx#Y0

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the example using delegate. The program should compile fine now.